# Draggable silverlight user control

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

I created a draggaable user control in silverlight, but having issues in moving the control inside page. Actually the issue is, dragged control moves out of page when dragging which i don't want. I want the control should drag inside the parent control only.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

```
Below is the code used to perform operation:
XAML:
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="LocalTranslateTransform"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
C#:
private void OnToolbarClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDownInToolbar = true;
    DragOffset = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot);
    toolbarBorder.CaptureMouse();
}

private void OnToolbarMoving(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDownInToolbar)
    {
        // we want to move it based on the position of the mouse
        moveUserControl(e);
    }
}

private void moveUserControl (MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot);
    Double newX = LocalTranslateTransform.X + (mousePos.X - DragOffset.X);
    Double newY = LocalTranslateTransform.Y + (mousePos.Y - DragOffset.Y);
    LocalTranslateTransform.X = newX;
    LocalTranslateTransform.Y = newY;
}

private void OnToolbarReleased(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDownInToolbar = false;
    toolbarBorder.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```

Comment: If you want to make your life easier, just drop the silverlight `MouseDragElementBehavior` onto the object and set `ConstrainToParentBounds="True"` and voila, done...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `TranslateTransform`, you're sending instructions to the compositor thread to display the element at X/Y offsets. It does not obey the rules of your panel and any visual tree member. So, you have to tell the compositor thread about the boundaries. Use `Clip` like this:

```
<Grid Width="500" Height="500">
  <Grid.Clip>
       <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,500,500" /> 
   </Grid.Clip>

   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <!-- This is the element being dragged by the mouse -->
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The `RectangleGeometry` will create a boundary where child elements are allowed to appear. Anything outside, will be clipped.

---

> After doing the desired changes this is how it looked.

[image]

---

**You need to create a constraint.**

Calculate if you're transforming the actual control outside the bounds of the parent.

```
private void moveUserControl (MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot);
    Double newX = LocalTranslateTransform.X + (mousePos.X - DragOffset.X);
    Double newY = LocalTranslateTransform.Y + (mousePos.Y - DragOffset.Y);

    var minX = 0;
    var maxX = 500 - ActualWidth; // 500 is parent width
    var minY = 0;
    var maxY = 500 - ActualHeight; // 500 is parent height

    if (newX < minX)
    {
        newX = minX;
    }
    else if (newX > maxX)
    {
        newX = maxX;
    } 

    if (newY < minY)
    {
        newY = minY;
    }
    else if (newY > maxY)
    {
        newY = maxY;
    } 

    LocalTranslateTransform.X = newX;
    LocalTranslateTransform.Y = newY;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry didn't get it properly. 
Where to add the Grid.Clip? In parent grid?

Comment: Yes, the parent grid (or any panel). Please look at my changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But I think i am missing something. Please check the attached image for details.